# firebase cloud functions: cannot read property 'environment' of undefined

Tags: database, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

am getting this error while I'm trying to deploy to a new firebase project using
firebase deploy --only functions command. I have two projects in use, one dev and one prod, I was working on prod and deploy worked well now too but when I added this project dev the deploying keeps working well in prod but in this new project dev no. I instead get this error:

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'environment' of undefined
at Object. (/home/projectId/Bitbucket/project-backend/functions/lib/db.js:6:35)

I added the key and eveything in cert/dev/firebase-dev.json in order to work.
The file db.js

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.db = void 0;
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const dir = functions.config().app.environment;
const certFile = `firebase-${dir}.json`;
//using admin SDK
const serviceAccount = require(__dirname + `/../cert/${dir}/${certFile}`);
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
.....
```

**Any Idea?** Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how did you set the environment configuration? And can you check it is correctly set **in the dev environment/project** with `firebase functions:config:get`?

Comment: Oh, thanks @RenaudTarnec I had a mistake in environment and now it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the error is `cannot read property 'environment' of undefined` and in your code we see

```
const dir = functions.config().app.environment;
```

the error seems to come from the environment configuration.

---

You should double check that the environment configuration is correctly set **in the dev environment/project**.

For that, you should use the `firebase functions:config:get` CLI command, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#retrieve_current_environment_configuration).