# Firebase functions deploy using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS failing to get an environment config on global scope

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using a [Service Account authentication](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#general) for deploying my firebase functions (using the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable). Here is my script:

```
cross-env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./file.json firebase --project=dev deploy --only functions
```

This is working great, it's deploying my firebase functions successfully.

However, when trying to use [Environment configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env), I'm getting an error when I'm trying to get one of my config vars, using the following standard code:

```
const domain = functions.config().env.domain;
```

This is **Only** happening when this code line is executed **outside** a function, meaning in the global scope.

This is the error I'm getting:

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'domain' of undefined

IMPORTANT NOTE: When I'm logged in to firebase using `firebase login` command, I'm not getting this error, I'm getting that error only when I'm logged out!

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you verify if where you've find the config parameter `functions.config().env.domain`? You can check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#install_and_configure_the_cloud_functions_shell) for additional details.

Comment: @RJC Yes, it's there for sure. Just like I wrote, when I make a login and executing the same deploy script it's working well.

Comment: Have you tried updating your Firebase version? Since as per checking, there is an updated [version](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) of the Firebase. Then after updating the version, kindly redeploy your function when logged in and when logged out.

Comment: @RJC I'm running latest version

Comment: please check out this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-credentials-helper it is my work, let me know if it was helpful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer from *firebase/firebase-tools* repo team, in [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3796).

> It seems likely that this is a permissions issue given the 403 response. Can you give your service account the roles/firebase.developAdmin role and see if it works after that?

That was really the problem. Once I added that role `roles/firebase.developAdmin` to the service account I'm deploying with, I managed to deploy successfully!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to replicate your code, and it's working fine on my end.

Here's what I included in my index.js file.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
 exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
   const domain = functions.config().env.domain;
   response.send(domain);
   
 });
```

And here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "cross-env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./key-file.json firebase --project=[Project-ID] deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
    "shared-types": "file:shared-types"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

After deploying the function while I was logged out in Firebase, I ran this CLI command for verification: `firebase functions:config:get`, and got this result:

```
{
  "env": {
    "domain": "test"
  }
}
```

Since your error is `Cannot read property 'domain' of undefined`, the error seems to come from your environment configuration. You should double check that the environment configuration is correctly set in the dev environment/project. For that, you should use the firebase `functions:config:get` CLI command, as explained in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#retrieve_current_environment_configuration). You can also check this [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67192479/firebase-cloud-functions-cannot-read-property-environment-of-undefined) I found.

Comment: It's impossible you got a result from `firebase functions:config:get` if you where logged out, you should have got this error: `Error: Failed to authenticate, have you run firebase login?` Therefore I believe you weren't logged out therefore your deploy worked. Please re-check yourself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was able to get a result from `firebase functions:config:get` because I am testing in Cloud Shell, where I'm authenticated using application default credentials. You can test it out on your local machine by following this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default).

Comment: May I also know if you're running your snippet locally? If so, Here's another SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841453/running-cloud-functions-locally-gives-error-functions-config-is-not-available) which explains that you need to setup `.runtimeconfig`.

Comment: I know now why it's working for you, it's because you're trying to access it from inside a function, try to access it from outside your function (in line 2 for example)

Comment: check my answer to see what was my problem. Thanks for your help.